# Add another language inline

Tags: html

I'm writing a paragraph that requires me to use a Greek word that means something else, but when I put the Greek word into my text editor and save it, it looks weird in my browser. I tried using a span but it still shows the same weird code.

```
<p>Music is an art form whose medium is sound and silence. Its common elements are pitch 
(which governs melody and harmony), rhythm (and its associated concepts tempo, meter, and 
articulation), dynamics, and the sonic qualities of timbre and texture. The word derives 
from Greek <span lang="el">μουσική</span> (mousike; "art of the Muses").</p>
```

Comment: When you say, "weird", do you mean it shows up as white boxes? If so, it seems you haven't put in the correct character set in your heading. Try, `<meta chatset="utf-8">` within `<head></head>`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your page is being interpreted using the wrong charset, try adding `<meta charset="UTF-8">` inside your `<head>` element. This tells the browser how to interpret more complex characters like you described.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure this tag is present in your `head`:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

ANSI and ISO charsets are the default when that tag is not present. ISO (the newest of those two) only supports 256 characters. UTF-8 character set allows you to use unicode characters directly in your HTML page.

That `meta` tag tells the browser to interpret your HTML page with the correct character set.

Check out the [wikipedia page on ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) for more info. Also, here's the [utf-8 wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

**Edit**

As Juhana pointed out in the comments, make sure your editor is set to the appropriate encoding as well (most programming/web-specific editors, like Sublime for example, should do this by default, but other multi-purpose text editors may not.)

Comment: This is partially correct. The meta tag doesn't help if the HTML file doesn't actually match the charset, so the text editor must be set to save UTF-8 as well.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the problem!...Kudos